# Invalid Addresses; nested exception is:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 501 5.5.2 RCPT TO syntax error (When i try to send mail)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-mail

I am facing some unknown type error, my code for sending the mail is as below

```
    String  mail_smtp_host=directoryPath("mail_smtp_host");
    final String mail_host_username=directoryPath("mail_host_username");
    final String mail_host_password=directoryPath("mail_host_password");
    String mail_smtp_port=directoryPath("mail_smtp_port");
    String set_from_emailid=directoryPath("set_from_emailid");
    String set_from_emailid3=directoryPath("set_from_emailid3");
    String set_from_emailid4=directoryPath("set_from_emailid4");
```

this all mail i am reading from property file

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", mail_smtp_host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", mail_smtp_port);

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(mail_host_username,mail_host_password);
            }
            });
    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mail_host_username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(checkemail));

        final String mail=""+set_from_emailid+","+set_from_emailid4+","+set_from_emailid3+"";
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, 
                InternetAddress.parse(mail));
```

Here i am setting multiple BCC mail id

```
mess = "Hello"
message.setContent(mess, "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        Transport.send(message);
```

It works in my local machine and mail is sent to the respect in BCC but as soon as deploy on ma test server it shows following error.

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;  nested exception is: 
  com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 501 5.5.2 RCPT TO syntax error
  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1196)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:584
```

enable to find the issue.
please help

Thanks

Comment: I've seen this error before from certain special characters being in the email addresses in the "To:" field.  Is that a possibility here?

Answer (score 1):

See this list of [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Turn on [JavaMail session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and post the protocol trace so we can see exactly what the server is complaining about.

Most likely there's something wrong with one of the addresses you're using.

Comment: but the same code is running sucessfuly on my local with same email ID and all.

Comment: Obviously **something** is different; maybe not in your code, maybe in your configuration.  Compare the debug output from the two cases.  If you can't spot the difference, post it here, or send it to me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.